# How Do You Add A Timeout When Expecting Events In Corda Tests?

Tags: corda

During Corda testing with the DriverDSL you can [wait for state updates](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/tutorial-integration-testing.html#monitoring-changes-to-the-vaults).
e.g.

```
expectEvents(aliceVaultUpdates, true, () ->
        expect(cashVaultUpdateClass, update -> true, update -> {
            System.out.println("Alice got vault update of " + update);
            Amount<Issued<Currency>> amount = update.getProduced().iterator().next().getState().getData().getAmount();
            assertEquals(DOLLARS(1000), Structures.withoutIssuer(amount));
            return null;
        })
);
```

How do you add a timeout so the test doesn't wait forever when the expected update doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just use Junit to do this?

here's an example.

```
@Test(timeout = 500)
public void testInfiniteTametakingLoop() throws InterruptedException 
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

source: https://howtodoinjava.com/junit/how-to-force-timeout-in-jnuit-testcase-execution/